# lg(n!) = Θ(nlgn) Solving for Big-theta

Tags: big-o

Show that lg(n!) = Θ(nlgn) how to prove it? I used limit to determine order but I stuck at some point lim<sub>n to +inf</sub> lg(n^n)/lg(n!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.  (Maybe try http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
log(n!) = log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n-2) + .... + log(2)
Which can be directly seen as 
log(n!) < n*log(n)
log(n!) < c1*n*log(n)
log(n!) > c2*n*log(n)
for n > n0
We have some value of c1 and c2 such that
c1*n*log(n) <= log(n!) <= c2*n*log(n)

Sum ( i =1 to n) i > (n/2)log(n/2) = (n/2)log(n) - (n/2)log(2)

hence we can say that
log(n!) = Big-Theta(nlog(n))
```

Comment: What is the proof that there exists such a `c2`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : Yes, We have to show bound from both side in case of `Big-Theta`

Comment: `c1 and c2` both has to be greater than zero. There are many possible values of `c2`. Like if we puc `c2 = 1/n` condition satisfied.

Comment: `c2` has to be a *constant*.

Comment: I don't understand what that new edit is trying to say.  How is it related to a value of `c2`?